# Jquery, CSS - How to set element as first in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I dynamically generate a bunch of item, and that looks something like this:

```
<div class=gallery_wrapper>
<figure>...</figure>
<figure>...</figure>
<figure>...</figure>
<figure>...</figure>
......
</div>
```

There is a condition which checks if one of the **figure** meet the requirements and it then add class to that **figure** (class=main_img).

What I tried is to float **figure** to the right, and then float the one with class **main_img** to the left, but that works partially. There are 3 **figure** elements in the row, and with float method element with class is at the start of its row, not at the start of the list.

How can I set this element as first (at the beginning)?

Comment: Is actually just moving it to the beginning okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements are nodes in a tree. What you need is to relocate it to the beginning of its parent.

If your element is in a jQuery object referenced by `$elem`, then with jQuery you'd do this:

```
$elem.prependTo($elem.parent())
```

Or this:

```
$elem.parent().prepend($elem)
```